# Cat command is not dumping config files

Tags: linux, centos, symlink, cat

When I run `cat /smb.conf` I get `cat: /smb.conf: Is a directory` rather than the config files. Why isn't it dumping the config files?

Comment: Which config files should it dump?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the manual page `cat(1)`, it's summary here states "cat - concatenate files and print on the standard output". It takes *files*, and you are giving it a *directory*.